# How to populate a form on load or opening

Tags: acumatica

I have a screen which is a form view.  this form is populated by fields from a table / DAC, with the key field being a UserID - a guid type as found in the Acumatica users table.  What I want is for the form to pull up a saved record based on the userid found in the system, i.e., the AccessInfo.UserID value.   I have one record saved based on my userid - and I've tried all kinds of events and cache updates in code, but nothing works.  I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, but I'm not seeing it.

Short story:  Is there a way to have all the fields on the form populate when the form is opened, fetching that row based on the UserID that's found in the system?

Answer (score 0):

I've used various methods to initialize fields depending on context and use case. I believe FieldDefaulting event or PXDefault attribute could work.

For simple initialization, you can put the BQL request in PXDefault type parameter:

```
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<EPEmployee.bAccountID, 
                  Where<EPEmployee.userID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>>), 
           PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
```

For more complex initialization skip the BQL in the attribute:

```
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
```

And use FieldDefaulting event handler to initialize the value:

```
public virtual void DAC_UserID_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
   e.NewValue = [...];
}
```

After you have the fields properly initialized I think all you have to do is set the Current property of the DAC primary view to navigate to that record.

I had a glitch with setting Current that I believe was fixed using the PageLoadBehavior property but I can't explain what it does without looking further into the code because it isn't well documented:

```
<px:PXDataSource PageLoadBehavior="GoFirstRecord">
```

Comment: In what event would you set the Current property of the DAC primary view?  Do you have an example of the syntax for setting the 'Current property of the DAC'?

Comment: You can set it on any event executing on the UI thread. This is pretty much everywhere except in PXLongOperation context. In PXLongOperation you can create new graph and set current but shouldn't access the existing graph.

Comment: A common pattern you'll see is CreateInstance<Graph> followed by setting the current and using PXRedirectRequiredException to open the screen on the selected Current like this: APInvoiceEntry graph = CreateInstance<APInvoiceEntry>();
graph.Document.Current = graph.Document.Search<APInvoice.refNbr>(Document_History.Current.RefNbr, Document_History.Current.DocType);

throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, true, "Generated Document")
{
 Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow
};